# how to send notification to admin when database changed using event in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, events

i am using Events here for the update event to triger when ever some one update the special field in that database so now i can get the dd when the database get updated every thing is working but i just want to know how to send the admin a notificaion like email or some notification in message box or something similar when the update is done so here is the code :

```
//this is the message model
  protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    "updated" => MessageUpdated::class
];
```

and

```
//the messageupdated event is here and like this 
public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
die('This shows successfuly when update event trigers');
    }
```

now instead of that die i want to send some notification to admin.

Answer (score 0):

Use Observers
and in Observers you can Observe your models changing like delete create update. 
and for each of them you can create notifications
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#observers